# Flea jumping 5units on the x-y plane

Tags: combinatorics

A flea starts at the origin of the xy-plane and makes three jumps. Each time the flea jumps 5 units and lands at a lattice point (that is, a point with integer coordinates). How
many different final positions are there for the flea in the xy-plane?

My approach:
After the first move it can land on positions (3,4),(4,3),(4,-3),(-3,4),(-4,3),(3,-4),(-3,-4),(-4,-3),(0,5),(5,0),(0,-5),(-5,0).
Let these positions be $a_1,a_2,...,a_{12}$
Let A be the multiset={$3.a_1,3.a_2,...,3.a_{12}$}
After this it will make 2 more moves.
The final possible positions will be all the possible outcomes of sum of any 3 of the elements of the multiset A.
After second move there will be 73 final positions possible.
After this I am not able to proceed.pls help.

Comment: Basically, the moveset is $M=\{(\pm3,\pm4),(\pm5,0),(0,\pm5)\}$. So, you are looking for $|M+M+M|=|3M|$.

Comment: Now do some careful counting (which is a lot easier than it looks thanks to symmetry) and the answer should be apaprent.

Comment: Could you please show them to me? As I tried that only but not able to do it

Comment: Consider the landing point as the new origin and you can replicate your same reasoning.

Comment: But there will be some same points after the second move. How am I supposed to know about them and they will increase after the third move.

Comment: Pls help........